# Bump Noise/Sound Before Audio Starts Playing

Tags: gnome, sound

There is strange bump right before audio starts playing on my OS. If I switch output source to monitor speakers, everything is fine, but if external speakers are enabled almost every time I can hear bump before audio.

I have tested it with another speakers and it's still happening. I am using Ubuntu 19.10.

This is probably related to system as I didn't experienced anything similar on Windows or Manjaro before.

Also, I have disabled loopback, but nothing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue on ubuntu 19.10, Card: HDA Intel PCH, Chip: Realtek ALC887-VD.
After searching online it looks like in my case it had something to do with power-save feature of the card.

Bump noise was gone after disabling power-save by adding

```
options snd-hda-intel power_save=0
```

at the bottom of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and rebooting. Now using

```
cat /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

shows 0 (zero). If you don't have /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf you can also try adding the same line at /etc/modprobe.d/snd_hda_intel.conf.
Commenting out `load-module module-suspend-on-idle` as mentioned here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116978 may also be needed. I didn't do that in my case.